# Notepad ++ copy text many times and increase number

Tags: notepad++

how to copy this text to notepad ++ but i like numbers to increase example if i copy text with number 1  in next copy it will be number 2

```
function myPlay1() {

$("#g1").addClass("intro"); 
}
function myEnd1()

{    
$("#g1").removeClass("intro");
var audio = document.getElementById("au2");
audio.play();

}
function myPause1()
{
$("#g1").removeClass("intro");

}
```

So if i copy this 30 times there   it will be like this

```
function myPlay30() {

$("#g30").addClass("intro"); 
}
function myEnd1()

{    
$("#g30").removeClass("intro");
var audio = document.getElementById("au31");
audio.play();

}
function myPause30()
{
$("#g30").removeClass("intro");

}
```

Comment: I would use a PHP or c# script to generate the Javascript directly in a file... Like a code generator.

Comment: Is there a reason you need duplicate this functionality 30 times?